# What is "letter of intent"

Tags: postdocs

I was applying for a post doc then come across one thing call letter of intent. What is letter of intent and How to make it. It is written that it is required.

Comment: How far into the process are you?

Comment: @ Buffy . I haven't started yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't yet started the process, then a letter of intent is probably just a notice that you intend to apply and when. If you are required to have a supervisor as part of the application process then you may need to indicate who you are working with to that end.

Late in the process it would be different, more likely an indication that you would accept an offer if it is made.

I don't think this is a common thing, however. Perhaps you should just ask the university or lab.

Comment: If you required to have a supervisor as part of.... Did you mean as postdoc or current supervisor.

Comment: I meant as a post-doc. Some places and fields might require this. I suspect that it would be less of an issue in something like math and more of one in, say, organic chemistry. And possibly more likely in EU, also. They may want to know who you intend to work with primarily. It would probably be good to state that if you know, even if it isn't a strict requirement.

Comment: Some grant proposals also have a "letter of intent" stage before proposal submission.  This allows the program managers to know how many proposals are likely to be submitted and recruit an appropriate number of reviewers without having to wait until the submission deadline to start recruiting reviewers.